Is the map $\mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^1$, $[z:1] \mapsto [e^z:1]$, $[1:0] \mapsto [1:0]$ smooth?
Is the map $\mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^1$, $[z:1] \mapsto [e^z:1]$, $[1:0] \mapsto [1:0]$ smooth?
More generally, if we want to show that maps are not smooth, what would be a handy invariant under smooth maps that we can exploit? (For example, if we want to show a map is not continuous, we can show that it does not preserve compact sets.)

Related

This map is not even continuous at $[1: 0]$. Indeed, the sequence $a_n = [-n: 1]$ converges to $[1:0]$, but the values of your function converge to $[0:1]$ rather than $[1:0]$ along this sequence.
For the more general question, there are two charts, the chart where $x_0 \neq 0$ and the chart where $x_1 \neq 0$ that cover this space, and you can check smoothness by checking on those charts. This is usually quite concrete since you're just rewriting everything as a function of either $x_1 / x_0$ or $x_0 / x_1$.

Thanks. For the more general question, what if I want to show the functions are not smooth? If I am not mistaken, then we have to check that any atlas is not smooth right? That is a much difficult task then just checking the two nice charts are smooth.

@BockmanCheung It's not as bad as that -- if it fails to be smooth on one chart, it's not smooth.

What you were saying was that it suffices to show that the function is not smooth at one point. I am wondering, however, why is it not possible that the function is smooth at a point on this chart, but if we have another atlas then the function would be smooth at another chart?

Oh wait, another atlas gives another smooth structure. I see what you mean now, we are fixing one smooth structure. The standard smooth structure on CP1 is determined by the two standard charts, and any other charts must be in the same equivalence class.

Hunter's answer gives an easy way of seeing that the function is discontinuous.
Another way of seeing this is as below:
The Riemann sphere is the one-point compactification of the complex plane and we are trying to extend the exponential function on the complex plane to the sphere by sending north pole (the point at infinity)  to itself.
Now give $z$ real positive values, denoted by a real variable $x$, we get $e^{2\pi x}$ will grow unboundedly. On the other hand  giving $z$ purely imaginary values   we get $ix\mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$ will be a complex number of unit modulus.
Conclusion: on real axis the function is unbounded, on imaginary axis it is bounded. But all lines though the origin in the plane pass through the north pole on the sphere, and we can see that there is no way to extend this function continuously to the whole sphere. So any extension to infinity will be discontinuous, not just the one you suggested.
